# Why do I need to cast from double to int, but not vice versa?

Tags: java, variables, casting

Let's say I have a double and an int.

```
double x = 5;
int y = x;
```

When I do this, it throws an error because I need to explicitly cast from double to int like this,

```
int y = (int) x;
```

for it to work. But when I do

```
int x = 5;
double y = x;
```

No error is thrown, and it works perfectly fine. Is there any reasoning behind having to explicitly cast from double to int but not vice versa?

Comment: Because an Integer is a Double but a Double is not an integer.

Comment: It's like a story with square and rectangle.

Comment: Because widening conversions are benign but narrowing conversions aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Double is more widened type than int. [According to specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) you can assign the value in this order:

```
byte -> short -> int -> long -> float -> double
```

The main idea:

> A **widening** primitive conversion does not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value.

But:

> A **narrowing** primitive conversion may lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and range.

Comment: Hmm. Then any idea what is against the idea of parsing boolean to byte or whatever? It is `true` or `false` for sure, but it represents 1 bit, so why not cast to byte?

Comment: @AdamMacierzyński can you rephrases?  Are you asking why `byte b = true` is not allowed?

Comment: Yeah. More or less that's what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

Because when you cast an integer to a double it's the same saying 1 or 1.0. But when you cast from double to int it isn't the same saying 1.8 or 1 and then you have to explicitly cast it.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from losing accuracy, they have different sizes.

Think of trying to get a wardrobe out of a truck and into a car boot. That's not going to work, but taking a box from a car boot to a truck, will work.

int is 2 to 4 bytes whereas a double is 8 bytes as explained here [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

- a int is stored using **32 bits** of memory. It represents **integers** between *-2^31* and a maximum value of *2^31-1*.
- a double is stored using **64 bits** of memory. It represents **floating numbers** between *2^-1074* and *(2-2^-52)·2^1023*.

**int to double**

Given the size of a double in memory, it is obvious that a double can contain an int (who can do more can do less).

**double to int**

This cast is not permitted since we lose information. 
If we would like to convert for example a floating number like 1.1618, we lose information. "Equivalents" of this double could be 1 or 2 but Java will never decide for you between the possibilities through the symbol '='. You have to use a function like for example `Math.round(1.1618);` to choose which conversion you want to transform your double to an int.